# What does ObjectName(parameter) refer in the structure OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE?

Tags: c, windows, kernel

I found this structure called OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE in one of the nt dll functions..I was curious to know about that structure and I went through its documentation(msdn)...In the OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE structure there is a parameter called PUNICODE_STRING objectName...As per the msdn documentation..it says that the objectName "the name of the object for which a handle is to be opened" which is actually a name or some root directory,am confused with this.Can anybody explain this term "name of the object"(root directory).what it represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure is used by device drivers and other kernel mode code to specify attributes of file objects. When you open a file with the [NtOpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432381(VS.85).aspx) or [IoCreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548418(VS.85).aspx) functions, you have to pass an `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` with the name of the file.

The `ObjectName` member of the structure is simply a pointer to an `UNICODE_STRING` structure containing the file or directory name.

Comment: I guess this isnt related to myquestion..my question is all about a i/p parameter called(PUNICODE_STRING objectName) of OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE.

Comment: It is related indeed. If you want to open a file with NtOpenFile, you have to pass to that function a pointer to an OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE structure, with its member ObjectName pointing to an UNICODE_STRING structure containing the file or directory name.